# Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3 -x^2 + x + 2$. Express $(\alpha ^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha ^2-\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3 -x^2 + x + 2$. Express $(\alpha ^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha ^2-\alpha)$ in the form $\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$

Having trouble approaching this problem.

Comment: Hint: If $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + x + 2$, what is the value of $f(\alpha)$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan zero

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Perhaps part of the issue is I believe the form you want is $a(\alpha)^2 + b\alpha + c$, since otherwise what does $a$ refer to in your "$a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$" part. I was starting to answer this when I got the same result to that of Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc's answer, i.e., no quadratic term, so since I discarded it as I saw no way to get what you were asking for otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For any root $\alpha$ you have

- $\alpha^3 = \alpha^2 - \alpha - 2$

Now, note that

- $(\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha^2-\alpha) = \alpha(\alpha^3-1)$

Now, replace $\alpha^3$ once and in the resulting term a second time. This will give the searched for expression.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\alpha$ is a root then $$\alpha^3=\alpha^2-\alpha-2 ~~~(1)$$
Then use (1) successively  to reduce $$f=(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(\alpha^2-\alpha)~~~~(2)=\alpha^4-\alpha= \alpha(\alpha^2-\alpha-2)-\alpha$$ $$=\alpha^3-\alpha^2-2\alpha=\alpha^2-\alpha-2-\alpha^2-3\alpha=-4\alpha-2$$ which is non
quadratic. It is like deviding the quartic (2) inby the cubic in (1) and looking for the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Express every thing in terms of degree of $\alpha$ as in f(X) and use remainder theorem for detailed solution kindly check this link https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/discussion-forum/topic/polynomial-equation-remainder-theorem/#postid-123